# check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies. Can not access java.lang.Object

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an android project and using java 8 and and kotlin 1.3.72. Some of my files in java and some in kotlin.
I am getting an error in my almost all files. 
"Can not access java.lang.Object, check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies".

Can anyone tell where i will wrong.

Comment: Try Build-> Rebuild Project.

Comment: i already tried this

Comment: Invalidate, restart, reimport, project settings > check for any errors there.